# Books with SAGE portions

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, sagemath

I recently finished working through *Adventures in Group Theory* and really appreciated the use of SageMath it employs. I considered myself moderately proficient with Sage, but I found working through the examples to be enormously beneficial to my understanding of Sage's capabilities.

To that end, I was curious to hear of other suggestions for mathematics texts that include work in Sage? Preferably ones accessible to undergraduates later in their degree or to newer graduate students.

Comment: http://www.sagemath.org/library-publications.html

Comment: I don't know how much group theory you know, but Gallian's textbook includes programming exercises in most chapters. It is probably not worth the cost, but if you can find it in a library you might enjoy trying some of them out in Sage.

Answer (score 4):

@Moo rightly suggests you look at the [list of books on the SageMath website](http://www.sagemath.org/library-publications.html#books).    There are many more for specific disciplines in mathematics, such as [Beezer's linear algebra text](http://linear.ups.edu/) or [Stein's undergraduate number theory text](http://www.wstein.org/ent) - and more to come, including one by yours truly not quite unleashed.  Our [publications issue list](https://github.com/sagemath/publications/issues) currently has several others hot off the presses, though not all those necessarily have lots of Sage directly in them; many just have some supplements or worksheets with Sage material.

That said, let me suggest a couple specific generalist ones you will probably find useful.

- Gregory V. Bard. [Sage for Undergraduates.](http://www.gregorybard.com/SAGE.html) American Mathematical Society, 2014.  Available freely online and definitely aimed at beginners, though more in a teaching context than with respect to any particular question.
- Craig Finch. [Sage Beginner's Guide.](http://www.packtpub.com/sage-beginners-guide/book) Packt Publishing, 2011.  Not free but pretty good and written by someone not otherwise affiliated with the project, which means has helpful hints for those not intimately familiar with it.

Comment: I hadn't thought to look on the SageMath website. That's a great list! Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: In the mean time a lot of books at https://mathbook.pugetsound.edu in the "Gallery" may also be good examples.

Answer (score 3):

The book by Zimmermann and others, initially published in French as

- [Calcul mathématique avec Sage](http://sagebook.gforge.inria.fr/)

is now available in English as

- [Computational Mathematics with SageMath](http://sagebook.gforge.inria.fr/english.html)

and in German as

- [Rechnen mit Sage](https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/sagebook/CalculDeutsch.pdf)

It teaches its readers both some mathematics and some basics
of computational mathematics, alongside a lot on SageMath.